# Can I manually delete the .log and .bak files from the MSSQL\Backup folder?

Tags: sql-server

As the title states. The drive is filling up with disk space. Can I manually delete the .log and .bak files from Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup folder? There are 6 months worth of it. Meaning, can't I just navigate to that folder via File Explorer, highlight 3 months worth, right-click and delete?

Comment: of course you can.. but whether you should or not is a different story!

Comment: Part of a good backup strategy is also deleting backups after you don't need them. Only you know how long you should keep backups for. I *doubt*, however, that you need backups from every day/week(?) for the last 6 months.

Comment: Harry can you expand on that? I'm new to this. What's the difference between deleting it like how I stated and deleting it through SSMS? @Larnu you're correct. We don't need 6 months of it. I've since changed it to purge at 3 months.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Ola Hallengren's maintenance solution - it's super easy to configure backups and also the retention period, and it will automatically delete older backups as part of the backup process; you can even configure it to delete old backups before or after the current backup is completed.

Ola's solution is very widely used and supported.

[Ola Hallengren Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/)